# SSIS - Calling second table based on first table

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have 2 tables T1 and T2 like this :

```
Create table #T1(ID int)
Insert into #T1 values(10),(20),(30)

Create table #T2(Val varchar(10))
Insert into #T2 values ('A'),('B'),('C'),('D')

output:
-----------
Table1 - ID
-----------
10
20
30
----------
Table2 - Val
----------
A
B
C
D
```

I want to store output in Flat file destination such that it looks like

```
10,A,B,C,D 20,A,B,C,D 30,A,B,C,D.
```

I know how to use joins but don't want to use them.

Please help me out as I am comparatively new to SSIS 2012. I am *trying to implement using For-Each loop* but not getting success at all.

A step wise solution will be appreciated. It should be like for each entry of T1, a loop will run for T2.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM T1,T2`

Comment: nope, that is creating cross join between t1 and t2..that i don't want.
It should be like for each entry of T1, a loop will run for T2.

Comment: You could store the values from T1 in an object variable (Using Execute SQL task) and then use a For Each loop to process each occurrence of that variable. This For Each loop would then query T2 and combine T1 & T2 to produce output.

Comment: What went wrong with your attempt with the foreach loop?   Did you get an error?   Please add it to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Control flow/data flow]

1. Create variables for object and item
2. Create a SQL statement to extract data from T1 and store in object variable. Set the ResultSet to "Full result set" and map the Result SetResult Name(3)
3. Add a Foreach Loop Container using the Foreach ADO enumerator
   Use the Object variable as the source variable and map to the item (5).
4. Add a dataflow. 
   In the data flow assign the T2 table as the DB source
5. Add a derived column and add the item variable as an extra column
6. Map the derived column and the T2 data to your output flatfile

Comment: thank you very much @MiguelH
I was missing the script task....please could you tell me why do we have to use script task here ?

Comment: Hi @PrabhatG. I included a script task simply to confirm that the for..each loop was providing the correct data. It has no real effect on anything. For completeness, this has `varTblitem` as a `ReadOnly Variable` and has the following line of script in the `Main` logic : `MsgBox(Dts.Variables("varTblitem").Value.ToString)`. I disable this script element once I can see everything working the way it should!